# conversion error double to integer vb.net - advantage database server

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, sql-insert, advantage-database-server

I'm getting this error when my program inserts CSV files into Advantage database Server, so my primitive solution was to insert lines parameterized:

```
Private Sub AddParameters(ByRef db As DBUmgebung.cdb.SQL, r As SeekZeilen)
        Try
            For i As Integer = 0 To r.erste_Zeile.Length - 1
                Dim value As String = ZeichensatzAnpassen(r._Rest(i))

                If value = "" Then
                    db.FeldWertChar(r.erste_Zeile(i), DBNull.Value)

                ElseIf value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(value) Then
                    db.FeldWertChar(r.erste_Zeile(i), DBNull.Value)

                ElseIf IsNumeric(value) Then
                    If value.Contains(",") Then
                        db.FeldWertDecimal(r.erste_Zeile(i), value.Replace(",", "."))
                    Else

                        db.FeldWertInteger(r.erste_Zeile(i), value)
                    End If

                    ElseIf IsDate(value) Then
                        db.FeldWertDate(r.erste_Zeile(i), value)

                    Else
                        db.FeldWertChar(r.erste_Zeile(i), value)

                    End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

so this function recognizes when a data set is a string, double, data or integer but if one of data sets is empty but double it will be treated as integer so i get the following error. does anyone have a better solution to recognize data types? Because i don't see any other Solutions as automatically to read the SQLCreateFile.txt returning the data types

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's the `SQLCreateFile.txt`-file? Where do you use it? What error do you get exactly and where? Your `value` is a string so there is no automatic type detection possible. Your `value.Replace(",", ".")` is awkward, what's if the value contains thousand-group separators or the input culture changes? Use `Decimal.TryParse` to check if a string can be converted to a `Decimal`, similar with `Double` or `Integer`.

Comment: i mean the file that contains all SQL create commands, i get the error when my program inserts all lines in a for each loop. and there are only numbers which are either integer or double, all numbers which contain , need to be replaced by . and recognized as double

Comment: What does *empty but double it will be treated as integer* mean? It can't be *empty but double*, as it's *either* empty or double; it can't be both at the same time

Comment: i mean a double can be empty and integer as well, thats the problem, i need algorithm that can recognize if it's a double or integer even when the field is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate over Case distinction like this:

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(node.GetType()))
{
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
        ' Handle Decimal
        break;

    case TypeCode.Int32:
        ' Handle Int32
        break;
     '...
}
```

Comment: There is no XML or HTML here, and therefore no `node` to have a `.GetType`. This question is about importing text from a .CSV file. Therefore, there is no `GetType`, and no `TypeCode`.